# Angular2 flush services data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular2 app where user can log in and log out and I need to flush services data on log out, because they hold some data and backend subscriptions (websocket). Currently the only way I found is to reload the page after log out, but it's a crunchy solution. So, is there some convenient way to reinstantiate services (or remove the data they hold) in Angular2?

Comment: Why don't you use a method in that service to rest all properties and call it in log outing?

Comment: @HassanFalahi, yes, it'll work, but I have several services and I thought maybe there is more convenient way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about moving all your initialization logic to a method of that service, i.e `init()` then call that from the constructor when the application starts or on user logout.